# Combining several datasets in a Netezza System

Tags: import, sas, export, union, netezza

We have a database with 65 tables that begin with Mon_Tues_Wed_201701 through Mon_Tues_Wed_202205. We create new tables with the naming convention of Mon_Tues_Wed_yyyymm so obviously it's growing. Each table contains about 1m-2m rows.

Here's what we want to do:

1. Union all Tables into one table
2. Do so automatically so all we have to do is hit the run statement -- no intervention or manual changes
3. Create a final table that is the union of the 65+ other views.
4. Bonus: if each table can have a column added (while being unioned) the name of the view (ie Source = 'Mon_Tues_Wed_202205' that would be appreciated.

We are currently doing this in SAS on a Grid System:

1. Importing the data from Netezza
2. Adding the Bonus column
3. Unioning the data
4. Exporting back to Netezza

Unfortunately this process takes 6 hours (1+ min per view import for a total time of 65+ min, 15 min to add the variables,  2+ hours to export to Netezza).

If you can show me code that would do the above, I'd really be grateful. I'm new to Netezza and it seems many of the rules from T-SQL processing do not apply.

Thank you

Paula

Comment: Usually you create partitions like that for efficiency. What are you trying to gain by stacking them all together? Are you creating any indexes to make access this data more efficient? If you can live without the bonus column, does proc append make the process faster?

Comment: Thanks but the client wants it all in one dataset to make it easier for his users (no join). It's been 6+ hours already and the transfer from SAS to Netezza is still running. That's why I'd prefer to keep it on native Nateeza but I don't  know SQL as well as I know SAS.

Thank you

Comment: Probably the most important thing to understand is what functions can be passed to Netezza through the ACCESS interface. Using an unsupported function will cause it to transfer all of the data to SAS before processing which can take a considerable amount of time with large datasets. https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n0s7avatiu8h5fn108omwq1yqcip.htm. If you want to ensure everything runs in-DB, use the SQL passthrough facility.

Comment: Also: consider using the `bulkload=yes` and `bulkunload=yes` dataset options. https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n119slgt394onmn12yd81pyytvin.htm

Comment: Definitely recommend pass through, doing the work on the DB is definitely more efficient. You can use SAS to coordinate the work though. How does your 65 table names look like, it terms of what is the first date and how do you know what is the last?Is it year/week?

Comment: FYI - TSQL is Microsoft SQL, Netezza is a different SQL variant.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- This can be done dynamically via a Stored Procedure
-- For example ...

    create or replace procedure my_dynamic_sql()
        returns integer
        language nzplsql
        execute as caller
    as begin_proc
    
    DECLARE
        tables RECORD;
        my_sql VARCHAR;
        union_statement VARCHAR;
        newline VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
    
        newline := chr(10);
        union_statement := '';
    
        my_sql := 'create table MON_TUES_WED_SUMMARY as' || newline ;
    
        raise notice 'Generating dynamic sql for';
    
        FOR tables IN
        SELECT TABLENAME FROM _V_TABLE WHERE OBJTYPE = 'TABLE' AND upper(TABLENAME) LIKE 'MON_TUES_WED_______' ORDER BY 1
        LOOP
    
            raise notice '     Table: %', tables.tablename;
    
            my_sql := my_sql || union_statement || 'select ''' || tables.tablename || '''::varchar(128) as source_table, * from ' || tables.tablename ;
    
            union_statement := ' union all' || newline ;
    
        END LOOP;
    
        raise notice 'Dropping the OLD results table';
        execute immediate 'DROP TABLE MON_TUES_WED_SUMMARY IF EXISTS;';
    
        raise notice 'The SQL looks like this %', my_sql;
    
        raise notice 'Executing the sql now ...';
        execute immediate my_sql;
    
        raise notice 'Done creating table MON_TUES_WED_SUMMARY';
    
    end;
    end_proc;
    
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    -- Then, to invoke the stored procedure
    call my_dynamic_sql;
```